# Primary current expectation in unloaded toroidal transformer

Tags: transformer, reverse-engineering, toroid

#### Background

I found a hefty, 7 kg toroidal transformer in visually good condition at a flea market which I am trying to map out. This is part one: I am not sure about what is happening on the primary side.

It has seven individual windings with an estimated ratio of 36:**5**:**5**:3:3:2:2. Windings are roughly 1.4 mm² copper except the bolded which are 7.5 mm². Just a logotype and custom part number.

#### Assumptions

Because of the winding ratio, individual thickness, and being manufactured by a reputable Swedish company for what is likely a Swedish market, I am *assuming* that the main primary winding is meant for use with a 220 or 230 volt mains, and the whole transformer is designed for either a class B audio amplifier of several hundred watts, or a lab power supply, or anything else where you need dual 40 volts at 5-10 ampere each, and a regulated ±15 volts. From the weight of this, I'd say it's rated for around 1000 VA.

#### Measurement setup

After doing a couple of other tests with a variac I wanted to see how it behaved on higher voltages. I connected the primary side to the variac, left all the other windings open, and slowly increased the primary voltage while also measuring the no-load current through the primary side. After about 200 volts, it started growling a bit, and I didn't dare to try it above 220 because of the evil sound - as you can see, the primary current is increasing exponentially.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG9cm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Primary current vs. voltage of unloaded transformer]

#### Questions

Now I need help with interpreting this data and my assumptions. I am not very experienced with how transformers should behave. Can anyone shed some light here? I do have a few ideas, but they are just guesses. It's either:

- Normal for an *unloaded* transformer of this size, because something about the <strike>magic</strike>magnetic currents not being absorbed on the secondary side, causing distortions leading to increased power consumption on the primary.
- Normal for a transformer of this size. The no-load losses will still be pretty large, and the growling should go away when properly mounted and not just lying on the workbench.
- The transformer is designed for the US market, to give 2x15 VAC at 20 ampere each, and a couple of even lower voltages with a primary of 110 VAC.
- The transformer has been damaged (seems fine on low voltages and no load).
- Something else of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Above 150V, the transformer core is starting to saturate, so your assumption is wrong: This transformer is designed for 120VAC nominal.

Leave the Variac at that level and proceed with the rest of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Ferrite cores saturate at a given magnetic flux, this is a nice feature because the transformer limits the amount of power that can be sourced from mains. Apparently from your graph this starts to happen at 30VAC as 0.02A * 150V = 30VAC. If you need more power you will need a different transformer.

[image]
Source: https://www.coilgun.info/theorymath/saturation.htm